# Does file position indicator remain in the same place after I pass the file pointer to a function?

Tags: c, file, pointers, fseek

I used fseek in main() with a file position pointer to move the file position indicator a few spaces. After that, I pass this file pointer to a function that is gonna keep reading data but also is gonna be using fseek. When I pass the file pointer to the function if I use fseek with SEEK_CUR as one of the parameters, is the file position indicator gonna start from scratch or from where it was set in main()?

Comment: Should be easy enough to try it and see. What makes you think passing a FILE ptr as a parameter would change anything in the underlying file?

Comment: What's a "file position pointer"? Do you mean file handle?

Comment: Yes. I'll be surprised if it didn't.

Comment: Rather than discuss the code only, post it and let the code also speak for itself.